# jekyll BASE_PATH doesn't work

Tags: css, jekyll, base-path

create a repo in ithub "github.com/name/blog".in the _config i set BASE_PATH = ""name.github.io/blog", but it dosen't work",when visit the "name.github.io/blog/", find the probleam, css and js get failed, for example style.css request url  "name.github.io/assets/themes/sext-v/css/style.css", it should be "name.github.io/blog/assets/themes/sext-v/css/style.css".

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you wrote. Can you try to be clearer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have 2 Github repos: `name.github.io` and `blog`. You will be able to visit the blog repo at `name.github.io/blog` and you're wondering how to reference JS and CSS files from the `blog` repo, rather than the `name.github.io` repo?

A solution is to set `baseurl: "/blog"` in your `_config.yml` file. Now throughout your site, `/` will (still) point to the `name.github.io` root, but you can reference the `blog` JS and CSS files by putting `{{ site.baseurl }}` into their references: `{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/themes/sext-v/css/style.css`

Another is to hardcode in the `/blog` to the address `/blog/assets/themes/sext-v/css/style.css`. The reason you need this is that github pages is serving `name.github.io` as the root directory. If you want assets from somewhere else you'll need to specify that.